# unable to perform correct assertion for each cost in a json

Tags: groovy

I am trying to perform an assertion where if each cost = 25, the assertion should pass, else fail. I thought I got it to work but I can see the assertion passes even if the cost is not 25.

I think this line is incorrect:

```
assert json.cost.flatten().collect { new BigDecimal(it)}.collect{it == processonecost}
```

I have three costs in the json that is 26 but yet I have `processidonecost = 25`

Below is the code:

```
def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def json =  new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
def processonecost = 25

assert json.cost.flatten().collect { new BigDecimal(it)}.collect{it == processonecost}
```

The json output is simply:

```
{
cost: 26
cost: 26
cost: 26
}
```

I don't want to implement `processonecost = [25,25,25]` by the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.collect{it == processonecost}` will result in `[false, false, false]` which is `true`. It is true because it is a list that is not empty. What you actually wanted to do is `.every{it == processonecost}` which returns `true` if all elements fulfill the predicate and `false` otherwise.